# Javascript - having trouble with a function I wrote to fade images in

Tags: javascript, image, opacity, fade

So I have written a function whose purpose is to fade an image from 0 opacity, to 1. It is meant to increase the opacity by 0.1 every 100ms, for a total duration of 1s. The function will call, and it will increase the opacity, but it seems to simply wait for 100ms and set the opacity to 1 straight away. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Here are the code snippets relevant to the function and images that should be faded in. I appreciate any input =)

**Javascript:**

```
function setOpacity(id, num) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = num;
}

function imagePopUp(id){
    var step = 0.0;

    for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        step = i / 10;
        var num = step.toFixed(1);
        setTimeout(function(){setOpacity(id, num);}, 100);

    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id ="shadowWrapper">
    <div id ="imageContainer">
         <img class ="sideImages" src ="images/mini_race1.jpg" onclick ="imagePopUp('image1')"></img>
         <img class ="sideImages" src ="images/mini_race2.jpg" onclick ="imagePopUp('image2')"></img>
         <img class ="sideImages" src ="images/mini_race3.jpg" onclick ="imagePopUp('image3')"></img>
    </div>

          <img class ="hiddenImages" id ="image1" src ="images/race_around_ireland_01.jpg"></img>
          <img class ="hiddenImages" id ="image2" src ="images/race_around_ireland_02.jpg"></img>
          <img class ="hiddenImages" id ="image3" src ="images/race_around_ireland_03.jpg"></img>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#imageContainer {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 450px;
    left: 600px;
}

.sideImages {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 112px;
    border: 1px #94b62d solid;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.hiddenImages {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px black solid;
    left: 100px;
    opacity: 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are queuing all of the callbacks to execute 100ms from now.  `setInterval` doesn't "stack" or "queue" functions.

Additionally, the same `num` variable is getting captured in the closures you are creating, and it will have its final value when executed in each callback.

A fix for both issues would be to replace

```
setTimeout(function(){setOpacity(id, num);}, 100);
```

with

```
setTimeout(function(inum) {
    return function(){setOpacity(id, inum);};
}(num), i * 100);
```

Comment: Hm, this might actually be the real problem ;)

Comment: Yes, but actually you are partially correct too, since `num` is technically in the scope of the function.  I will edit the answer to account for this.